# psycopg2.errors.InvalidColumnReference: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

I'm trying to install an Odoo module but I got the above error. I use Odoo version 16. I guess the module was fine at first but don't know what happened. I used ChatGPT and it says:

> Verify the unique or exclusion constraint: Check the table definition
> in your database and confirm whether the column you're referring to
> has a unique or exclusion constraint defined. If it doesn't, you'll
> need to add the appropriate constraint to the column.
>
> Specify a different column: If the current column you're trying to use
> in the "ON CONFLICT" clause doesn't have a unique or exclusion
> constraint, you can select a different column that does have such a
> constraint. Modify your "INSERT" statement to use a column with the
> necessary constraint.
>
> Update the table schema: If you have control over the table schema and
> the specific constraint you require, you can modify the table
> definition to add the unique or exclusion constraint to the relevant
> column. Once the constraint is in place, you should be able to use the
> "ON CONFLICT" clause with that column.

I tried to figure it out but couldn't find the issue. Please any help is appreciated!!

The full logs are:

```
odoo.sql_db: bad query: 
        INSERT INTO "ir_model" ("model", "name", "order", "info", "state", "transient", "is_mail_thread", "is_mail_activity", "is_mail_blacklist") VALUES ('product.transfer.internal', '{"en_US": "Product Internal Transfer"}', 'id', ' Main super-class for regular database-persisted Odoo models.

    Odoo models are created by inheriting from this class::

        class user(Model):
            ...

    The system will later instantiate the class once per database (on
    which the class'' module is installed).
    ', 'base', false, true, true, false), ('product.transfer.internal.line', '{"en_US": "Product list for Product Internal Transfer"}', 'id', ' Main super-class for regular database-persisted Odoo models.

    Odoo models are created by inheriting from this class::

        class user(Model):
            ...

    The system will later instantiate the class once per database (on
    which the class'' module is installed).
    ', 'base', false, false, false, false), ('stock.location.product', '{"en_US": "stock.location.product"}', 'id', ' Main super-class for regular database-persisted Odoo models.

    Odoo models are created by inheriting from this class::

        class user(Model):
            ...

    The system will later instantiate the class once per database (on
    which the class'' module is installed).
    ', 'base', false, false, false, false)
        ON CONFLICT (model) DO UPDATE SET ("model", "name", "order", "info", "state", "transient", "is_mail_thread", "is_mail_activity", "is_mail_blacklist") = (EXCLUDED."model", EXCLUDED."name", EXCLUDED."order", EXCLUDED."info", EXCLUDED."state", EXCLUDED."transient", EXCLUDED."is_mail_thread", EXCLUDED."is_mail_activity", EXCLUDED."is_mail_blacklist")
        RETURNING id
    
ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
 
2023-08-08 17:41:05,161 55543 WARNING Gissah_KSA odoo.modules.loading: Transient module states were reset 
2023-08-08 17:41:05,168 55543 ERROR Gissah_KSA odoo.modules.registry: Failed to load registry 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 90, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 488, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 372, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 208, in load_module_graph
    registry.init_models(cr, model_names, {'module': package.name}, new_install)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 529, in init_models
    env['ir.model']._reflect_models(model_names)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 396, in _reflect_models
    ids = upsert_en(self, cols, rows, ['model'])
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 152, in upsert_en
    model.env.cr.execute(query, params)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/sql_db.py", line 321, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
psycopg2.errors.InvalidColumnReference: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

2023-08-08 17:41:05,171 55543 ERROR Gissah_KSA odoo.http: Exception during request handling. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/http.py", line 1998, in __call__
    response = request._serve_db()
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/http.py", line 1584, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 133, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/http.py", line 1611, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/http.py", line 1815, in dispatch
    result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 154, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/http.py", line 697, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 46, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 33, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/api.py", line 461, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/api.py", line 448, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-74>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 74, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 456, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 580, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "<decorator-gen-14>", line 2, in new
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/tools/func.py", line 87, in locked
    return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 90, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 488, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 372, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 208, in load_module_graph
    registry.init_models(cr, model_names, {'module': package.name}, new_install)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 529, in init_models
    env['ir.model']._reflect_models(model_names)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 396, in _reflect_models
    ids = upsert_en(self, cols, rows, ['model'])
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_model.py", line 152, in upsert_en
    model.env.cr.execute(query, params)
  File "/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/sql_db.py", line 321, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
psycopg2.errors.InvalidColumnReference: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

Comment: try to create a new db in order to see if it's something related to the current one or you could also replicate the error in a fresh new db. Also it will be helpful to see the code of the module. Seems that your model definition it's having some model name collision